# Conditional expectation when each of the random variables have the same density?

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

Assume I have a collection of random variables $\{P_t\}_{t=1}^\infty$. Also assume that the unconditional distribution of $P_t$ equals the unconditional distribution of $P_{t+n}$ for all $n$. What can we say about $\mathrm{E}(P_{t+n}|P_t)$?

Comment: Nothing, in general. If they are independent then the conidtional expectation is $EP_{t+n}$ and if they are equal it becomes $P_{t+n}$.

Comment: Thanks Kabo! I appreciate it.